# Accessing computed properties of overriden Shopware 6 vue component

Tags: vue.js, shopware6

I am overwriting `sw-category-tree` in Shopware 6:

```js
import template from './sw-category-tree.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.override('sw-category-tree', {
    template,
    methods: {
        async duplicateElement(contextItem) {
            const initContainer = Shopware.Application.getContainer('init');
            const headers = this.$super('computed').categoryRepository().buildHeaders();
```

Now I am trying to access the `categoryRepository` which is available via `this.categoryRepository` in the original component.

Above line yields an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '#sw-category-tree')`

What can be the reason?

I also tried `this.categoryRepository` and `this.$super.categoryRepository`

Actually I think

```js
this.$super('categoryRepository')
```

should work, but it prints the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Computed properties are just available using `this` - without any `$super` call:

`this.categoryRepository`

I think in earlier iterations of debugging this, I got confused because it's not available in the `then`-closure of the post a bit below.

This works well:

```js
Component.override('sw-category-tree', {
    template,
    methods: {
        async duplicateElement(contextItem) {
            const initContainer = Shopware.Application.getContainer('init');
            const headers = this.categoryRepository.buildHeaders();
            const httpClient = initContainer.httpClient;
            const that = this;
            await httpClient.post('/_admin/imidi-category-duplicator/clone-category/' + contextItem.id, {}, { headers }).then((clone) => {
                const criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setIds([clone.id]);
                that.categoryRepository.search(criteria).then((categories) => {
                    this.addCategories(categories);
                });
```